# How to store JSON string values in a String parameters?

Tags: json, oracle-maf

Oracle MCS CustomAPI response is a JSON String .I want to store the JSON string in separate String parameter to create datacontrol.

```
{
"Header": {
    "MessageID": "uE60F40847D",
    "ReplyTo": {
        "Address": "http:2005/08/addressing/anonymous"
    },
    "FaultTo": {
        "Address": "http://www.w3.org2005"
    }
},
"Body": {
    "processResponse": {
        "PERSON_ID": "45",
        "GROUPS_ID": "54",
        "PERSON_LOGIN": "s",
        "PERSON_ROLE": "s",
        "PERSON_UID": "4655",
        "PERSON_NAME": "Welcome! Sanka",
        "ERROR_CODE": "y",
        "ERROR_MSG": "Login Successful"
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step1.

Create a class called `Response` with parameters

```
private int responseCode;
private String responseMessage;
```

also generate getters and setters for the parameters.

### Step 2.

then from your `ServiceImplementation` class create an object of the class `Response` and set the response string to `<object>.setResponseMessage(<String containing your response>)` ;

### Step 3.

In  your bean or Pojo class

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response.getResponseMessage());
JSONObject headerObject = jsonObject.getJsonObject("Header");
```

then you will get all the "Header" parameters in the `headerObject` and you can have individual value by `headerObject.getString("<KeyName>")`.

Like above you can also parse "Body". Assign these values to an `ArrayList` and create datacontrol.

If you have any doubts in the steps , feel free to ask

Comment: As per sample MCS MAF utility I have to add step 2 in CustomAPIbacking

Comment: No problems... the codding structure depends on programmers

Comment: @Janaki .. Did you get it?

Comment: It is working fine for Header ,But how to get processResponse values?

Comment: first create a Body JSONObject like "HEADER" then create child JSONObject  for processResponse then you will get individual values from that child json object using getString() method.

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject1= new JSONObject(loginresponse1.getResponseMessage());
                  JSONObject headerObject1 = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("Body");
                  JSONObject headerObject12 = headerObject1.getJSONObject("processResponse"); I have created like this only

Comment: then : 
String personId=headerObject12 .getString("PERSON_ID");
Like this you will get al the paramenters

Comment: Anand raj.. Can you help me in creating List??

Comment: yes I got it. But now Iam trying with Json Array   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767439/how-to-convert-the-json-array-to-list-to-create-datacontrol-in-oracle-mcs/36767610#36767610