# How to convert the JSON array to List to create DataControl in oracle MCS?

Tags: oracle-maf

Iam trying to create a List View for the below Json code

```
{"ImageList" :[

 {
  "ENO":"87",
  "ENAME" : "john",
   "EJOB":"clerk",
  },{
    "ENO":"21",
    "ENAME" : "Abdul",
    "EJOB":"Manager",
  } ]
}
```

This the DataControl Program
This DataControl is invoked by another Class

```
 Runnable mcsJob = new Runnable(){
   public void run(){ 
   try {

           CustomAPI customApi = mobileBackend.getServiceProxyCustomApi();            
           MCSRequest request = new MCSRequest(mobileBackend.getMbeConfiguration());
           request.setConnectionName(mafConnection);            
           request.setRequestURI(requestURI);            
           request.setHttpMethod(httpMethod);            
           request.setPayload(payload==null?"":payload);
           request.setRetryLimit(0);
           HashMap<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String,String>();

           if(httpHeaders!=null)
           {
               headers.putAll(httpHeaders);
           }

           request.setHttpHeaders(headers);  
           MCSResponse response = customApi.sendForStringResponse(request);
           String jsonResponse = (String) response.getMessage(); 
           setEmployeeSearchResponse(jsonResponse);
           //Converting JSON string
           apiResponse.setEmpsearchResponse(employeeSearchResponse);
           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(apiResponse.getEmpsearchResponse());
           JSONObject bodyObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Body");
           JSONObject ProcessObject=bodyObject.getJSONObject("processResponse");
            JSONArray empObject=ProcessObject.getJSONArray("ImageList"); 

           for(int i=0;i<empObject.length();i++)

               {

                JSONObject js = empObject.getJSONObject(i); 
                String name= ""+js.getString("ENO");
                String photo = ""+js.getString("ENAME");
                String empno=""+js.getString("EJOB");
                 EmployeeSearchPOJO  empo=new EmployeeSearchPOJO();
                  empo.setEMPNO(empno);
                   empo.setENAME(name);
                   empo.setPHOTO(photo);   
                   employeeList.add(empo);

               }

      }
```

Then I will return the List

I have created EmployeeSearchPOJO class

List I have created is

```
List<EmployeeSearchPOJO> employeeList=new ArrayList<EmployeeSearchPOJO>();

public void setEmployeeList(List<EmployeeSearchPOJO> employeeList) {
    this.employeeList = employeeList;
}

public List<EmployeeSearchPOJO> getEmployeeList() {
    return employeeList;
}
```

Comment: Actually, why do you want to create DataControl in MCS?

Comment: yes I want to create DataControl for ListView

Comment: In MCS only.JSON output received from the CustomAPI of oracle MCS,Now Iam trying to Convert the JSON array to List

Comment: Actually what we are doing is that, we will parse the API response and will store it in DB. Then will create a POJO class with the response parameters then generate getters and setters. After that from our corresponding DataContoll class will create an arraylist of the type of POJO class and will fetch the values from DB to these arraylist
  
Then will use the ProviderChangeSupport in the setter method. After fetching the data in to arrayList , right click on the dc class and choose create data controll option

Comment: Is your requirement like this? We are using MCS as a middleware only

Comment: Yes,That is my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step1

create a table with columns as `ENO,ENAME,EJOB`.

### Step2

Create a `POJO` Class with response variables. Generate `get` and `set` methods.

### Step 3

Parse the `json` response and store it in to database.(This will increate the performance)

### Step4

Create a `class` which is to be acts as `datacontroll` and create an `arraylist` of the type of `pojo` class.
Generate `get and set` methods for the arraylist. 
In `set` method use `providerChangeSupport` .  Write a method return which will fetch the values from the `database` and store the result (returnType is `list`) in to the `setter` method of the `arraylist`. Call the method from the `constructor` of the dc class.

### Step5

Finally right click on the class and select `CreateDataControll`. Thenn from the application window of jdeveloper you can see the `list`  in the `Data Controlls` panel.

Comment: I have Created like that only ..I drag and dropped the List,but after reloading the Page only the list displays.

Comment: did you add the method action in pageDef ?

Comment: yes,I have created method (which is called during action)which sets  API URI and invokes datacontrol which call the customAPI and provides Jsonresponse .

Comment: What is your action? Are you creating data controll directly from  web service??

Comment: No,The JSONresponse is stored in variables or list using java which is converted into datacontrol

Comment: Then its Ok.. Try to add invokeMethodeAction also. Could you please show me what you have done? If i see your code sometimes i can help you.

Comment: Please add ProiderChangeSupport. Also i didnt see the method that add / set the value to your listView set method

Comment: employeeList.add(empo);  I have added

Comment: Create a method in dataControl class with return type of list which calls the above method. Then from the method created add the return type to the setEmployeeList method

Comment: You are asking me to create a new method which return the list and call the above method

Comment: Nop. From dataContoll class, create a new method which call the above method. the above method should return list and set the return to the setter method of the arrayList

Comment: The above method already return list ... how to set the return to the setter method

Comment: For example:
public void <method_name>(){
List imageList= <Call your method>;
setEmployeeList(imageList);}

call this method from the constructor of your dataControll class. Also add the above method to your pageDef file.

Comment: Show me your newly added method in dc

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I did like this..... public List<EmployeePOJO> EmployeeList(ActionEvent e)
    {
        List<EmployeePOJO> imageList=getEmployeeSearchs(); 
      
         setEmployeeList(imageList);
     return imageList;
      }

Comment: are you try to load the list on button click?

Comment: Actually what you want to do is bind action listener of button click to a method in your bean class. From there you have to invoke DC method.

Comment: Yes I understood,I am also using same method only ..Now you ask me to call method (which invokes datacontrol ) through ActionListner and call the List Method through Action...Am I right

Comment: I didn't know  that you want to invoke through button click.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it using GSON.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = myJsonString;
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyClass>>(){}.getType();
myList= gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without using Gson

Answer (score 0):

Since your JSONArray contains JSONObject with three attributes,you can create a java class with the exact same member variables i.e. for example

```
class Employee
{
    String ENO;
    String ENAME:
    String EJOB;

    //create getters ans setters
}
```

Then within your current code,add the following import:

```
import oracle.adfmf.framework.api.JSONBeanSerializationHelper;
```

and in the last loop you can write:

```
 Employee emp=(Employee) JSONBeanSerializationHelper.fromJSON(Employee .class,js);
employeeList.add(emp);
```

Now you can set employeeList in EmployeeSearchPOJO class and then use it to create the Data Control.